# GIF in XeLaTeX using animate

Tags: latex, animated-gif, xelatex

I am writing a document using the XeLaTeX compiler and would like to add a gif using the animate package. However, when I press play on the controls, I do not get an animation of the images whatsoever. I've attached a picture of what my code below outputs -> [Image of code output in my PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAi0x.png)

Sample images: [fakegif-0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9kBv.png) [fakegif-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5qfA.jpg) [fakegif-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pIiX.jpg)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,width=0.4\linewidth]{12}{fakegif-}{0}{2}
    \caption{Example animate}
\label{figure:gif images}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Could you clarify: compilable as in if you would like to test out my code?

Comment: Yes, a small but compilable document that we can copy&paste to test your code.

Comment: Done and done. I've added the example pictures within the post.